# How can I update columns in Table X only when a subsection of a string column in Table X matches an entire string column in Table Y?

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, sql-update, substring

## Framework & Goal

I am having trouble making the finishing touches on a project that involves updating null values for the columns *street_address*, *city*, *state*, *zip_code*, *latitude*, and *longitude* in Table X (called **source**) specifically for any *location_name* that has to do with Loves, Pilot, Flying J, TA, or Petro gas stations.

The **source table** contains a list of all transactions in my current database, and each transaction has a gas station location field. I am only trying to update these location-relevant columns in the table when a location is owned by one of the 5 providers I listed above (Loves, Pilot, etc.).

I also have three separate tables: **ta_petro_stores**, **pilot_flying_j_stores**, and **loves_stores**. Each of these tables contains a full list of store locations, and my goal is for me to pull the relevant address, city, latitude, etc. from each of these tables and update the null values in my source table with them.

## The Problem

Out of 1,588 unique Loves, Pilot, etc. locations, there are now only 208 which have been filled out with the exact same incorrect location information. The reason why my previous UPDATE attempts failed to account for transactions involving any of these 208 stores is because the *location_name* in source did not have an exact match in the *location* column of ta_petro_stores. For the loves_stores and pilot_flying_j tables, I matched their *store_num* column with a substring of the source table's *location_name* column that only pulled out the first number listed in it.

The majority of these "stragglers" are locations which have the proper city listed within source's *location_name*, for example, "TA MOCKSVILLE #6251", but don't match the *location* column in ta_petro_stores exactly. The *city* column in ta_petro_stores would have an exact match with a substringed-out *location_name* from the source table, but so far, I have been unable to come up with the proper syntax to achieve this. Also, if there is a way to account for a city with two "words" (i.e. a space in-between them, like "New York" or "Grand Rapids") in a query like this as well, please let me know.

## What I Have Attempted

In a nutshell, I have tried various forms of concatenation, substrings, and joins to try to get SQL to pull the city name form source's *location_name* column and compare it to the *city* column in each of the other three tables, but each attempt has resulted in every row of my data set having its location data overwritten by null values or a randomly selected address, city, state, zip, etc.

## My Code

```
/*Change remaining incorrect location data in source table (match by city name)*/
UPDATE source
SET
  street_address = tap.address,
  city = tap.city,
  state = tap.state,
  zip_code = tap.zipcode,
  latitude = tap.latitude,
  longitude = tap.longitude
FROM source AS s
JOIN ta_petro_stores AS tap ON lower(tap.city) like lower(substring(s.location_name, concat('%', tap.city, '%')))
WHERE s.street_address is null
    and (s.location_name like 'TA %' or s.location_name like 'PETRO%')
```

## Closing Thoughts

Thank you for taking the time to read this and respond. I am willing to provide any additional information that may help, including further explanation or additional images of table layouts, code, etc.

Comment: Welcome to the SO community. The community will help with your issues, but there are certain expectations on you. Please spend a few minuets to take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and review [ask]. 
 Then update your question to include sample data, table definition (ddl scripts), and the expected results of that data; all as text - **no images**. Adding a  [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/) is extremely useful.  The test data should include a few rows to be updated and few that are not updated. Your description is extensive, but I am nor sure it is clear.